# how do drawcalls work in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have numerous potentially long polylines (or short, vertices count is highly volatile) to display, so I was thinking about packing them in a bunch of fixed size (let's say 10000 vertices) position `BufferAttribute` and sending one `drawcall` per polyline. And if a polyline crosses the 10000 limit boundary, I can just split it, repeat the last vertex from the previous buffer as the first vertex of the new buffer and carry on with multiple `THREE.Line` objects.

My understanding is that a `drawcall` is defined by `addGroup()` in the recent three.js, but I have troubles understanding the link with `setDrawRange()`.

I replaced `setDrawRange()` by `addGroup()` in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/1v00pxx5/ and it doesn't animate anymore ( [Drawing a line with three.js dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31399856/drawing-a-line-with-three-js-dynamically) ).

I replaced :

```
line.geometry.setDrawRange( 0, drawCount );
```

by

```
line.geometry.clearGroups();
line.geometry.addGroup( 0, drawCount );
```

It looks like I misunderstood something, because it's rendering everything instead of just the single group I was defining.

Here is my crazy context: I am building a chrome packaged application that accesses the USB, and both webgl and USB have to be on the main JS thread, but sometimes when uploading the geometries to webgl, it starves the USB, and I can't use a bigger USB buffer because the device on the other side of the usb cable doesn't have enough memory.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32819344/buffergeometry-how-to-render-groups-of-faces/32824915#32824915. Does that answer your question?

Comment: I messed up my JSfiddle link the first time, sorry. I'm looking into the material thing, thanks.

Comment: Yes, perfect, that was the lack of multimaterial thing (strangely this answer did not appear in my googling), may I suggest that you regularize the interface? you could make setDrawRange() create a single group, and support non-multi materials as "the same material" for all the groups. Groups then also become the natural way cut a line_strip or a triangle_fan. You can report it as an answer if you want the brownie points ( here is the corrected link from your comment http://jsfiddle.net/1v00pxx5/1/ ).

Comment: Would you be willing to file a three.js enhancement request suggesting your simplified interface proposal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`BufferGeometry.groups` is now used to support multiple materials ( formerly `MultiMaterial` or `MeshFaceMaterial` ). For example,

```
geometry.clearGroups();
geometry.addGroup( start1, count1, 0 ); // materialIndex 0
geometry.addGroup( start2, count2, 1 ); // materialIndex 1

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, materialsArray );
```

Setting `geometry.drawRange` will render a sub-range of the geometry.

```
geometry.setDrawRange( start, count );

var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff0000 } );
var line = new THREE.Line( geometry, material );
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w67tzfhx/

three.js r.91

Comment: what do `start1`, `start2`, `count1`, and `count2` refer to here?

Comment: For others with the same question, see: https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/BufferGeometry.groups