# Hide/show parts of a BufferGeometry

Tags: three.js

I build a complex `BufferGeometry` from scratch and I am looking for a way to selectively hide or show sections of it - (I don't want to have to save the positions elsewhere so moving vertices around is not an option)

After reading the code a bit, I wondered if I could use `BufferGeometry.groups` except that I don't want/need a different material per group - maybe assigning a different material could work and I could make the opacity 0 for parts I don't want? However, here will be many thousands of groups though so I doubt that would be effective.

Started a JSFiddle with a boiled down example: http://jsfiddle.net/callum/x7y72k1e/

Is there a way to do it efficiently?

(As I'm typing this, I wonder if I just store the positions in a mirror attribute array and use that).

Comment: i need to catch up on 72 so i can't write a detailed answer, but i think you should look into adding custom buffer attributes. Basically you can add a group index to every vertex and clip that in the shader. Otherwise, groups and different materials is probably the only way to go. But its going to be pretty inefficient.

Comment: In your fiddle, just set `geometry.drawRange.count = 0;` // or `Infinity`. Alternatively see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32819344/buffergeometry-how-to-render-groups-of-faces/32824915#32824915. Or use `discard` in a custom shader based on an attribute value. Do any of those ideas meet your needs?

Comment: I don't think drawRange will work for me since the vertices I want to draw are scattered throughout the `BufferGeometry` versus being the first N

I tried using groups with different materials and it worked but for the large number of groups I require, it wasn't performant on my modest system: http://jsfiddle.net/callum/x7y72k1e/3/

Maybe a shader will work best but I have to read up on how to do that.

Comment: Ok - I think I figured out how to get what I want using a shader. http://jsfiddle.net/callum/x7y72k1e/10

I had to pass an attribute around between the two shaders but it seems to work well and of course, is very fast. 

Not sure why my visible array needs to be twice as big as I expected