# THREE.MultiMaterial has been removed. Use an Array instead

Tags: three.js

I've created a sketchup model of a building and exported it to a `.dae` and texture file. I want to display it in the browser using [three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/), but I get the error `THREE.MultiMaterial has been removed. Use an Array instead`. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 15):

In new version of three.js you must use simple array with (items) materilas not  multimaterial objects. Here is example :

```js
    var geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
    var materials = [
        new THREE.MeshDepthMaterial(),
        new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial(),
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { wireframe: true } ),
        new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0xff0000 } ),
        new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0x0000ff } ),
        new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } ),
    ];
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, materials );
```

Also important! Access looks like  :

```js
    if ( Array.isArray( object.material ) ) {
        for ( var m = 0; m < object.material.length; m++ ) {
            object.material[ m ].color.set( 0xffffff );
        }
    } else {
        object.material.color.set( 0xffffff );
    }
```

On some older ver of browsers `isArray` is not supported.
In that case use :

```js
   if (typeof object.material.length !== 'undefined' ) {
     // your code
   }
```

I am glad for this improvement. I don't like too much theory and complex programming paradigm. Best way is: make it simple when you can.

Comment: This isn't working for me. I've two materials that work independently but when I pass either or both as an array I get nothing. Console.log of mesh.material does output an array but I don't see my object. Are there any gotchas?

Comment: Passing a materials array doesn't work as I expected hence my issue. Wrongly assumed it'd layer the materials.

Comment: @defmech post most relevant part of your code if you want help from community.